# Is there a way to create a logical variable based on the first letter of another variable?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the tweets of many people, and their corresponding MBTI personality.
I would like to add another variable to the dataset that is a logical, only based on whether the first letter in their MBTI code, i.e. TRUE if they are extroverts, and FALSE if they are introverts. How could i do this?
I tried something like this:

mbti : is the dataset
type : a variable within the set that gives the different types

```
mbti <- mbti %>%
    `if`(mbti$type == `startsWith`("E")){
    `mutate`(extrovert = TRUE)
   } `else`{
   `mutate`(extrovert = FALSE)
}
```

i have tried several other variations, including this inside a `for` loop, since i want to iterate over many different individuals.
Sorry if this is a stupid question, or poorly framed, i am quite new to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest reading [An Introduction to dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) - I think it will help clear up some misconceptions you have. Or perhaps general introductions to R. Many (most!) R functions are vectorized, so you don't need loops. `startsWith` is vectorized, thus we can run it on all your individuals at once. And it already returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so we can directly assign the result to the `startsWith` output.

```
## startsWith example
startsWith(c("Echo", "Elephant", "Not an E"), "E")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

## using it for your problem
mbti <- mbti %>%
  mutate(extrovert = startsWith(type, "E"))
```

`if(){}else{}`, however, is one of the exceptions - it is not vectorized, and is used for controlling what code gets run. `ifelse()` is vectorized function that we could use, e.g., if you wanted the result to be "Extroverted" if type startw with an E and "Introverted" otherwise (see below). But we don't need it here because you want `TRUE/FALSE` and `startsWith` returns `TRUE/FALSE`:

```
## an ifelse() example
mbti <- mbti %>%
  mutate(vertedness = ifelse(startsWith(type, "E"), "Extrovert", "Introvert))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `ifelse` directly.  Say your new column is `Etype` then

```
mbti$Etype <- ifelse(substring(mbti$type, 1, 1) == "E", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: No `ifelse` needed. `ifelse(test, TRUE, FALSE)` is a long way to write `test`.

Comment: You lost me.  Why use dplyr rather than base R?

Comment: I used `dplyr` in my answer because OP was trying to use `dplyr` in the question. But here I'm saying that in your answer `ifelse` isn't needed. `mbti$Etype <- ifelse(substring(mbti$type, 1, 1) == "E", TRUE, FALSE)` is equivalent to `mbti$Etype <- substring(mbti$type, 1, 1) == "E"`. `==` already returns `TRUE/FALSE`, so your `ifelse()` is changing `TRUE/FALSE` to `TRUE/FALSE` - it's redundant.

Comment: Or even use `startsWith` as OP did in the question (it is also in `base`) `mbti$Etype <- startsWith(mbti$type, "E")`.